# Excel VBA to select a range based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA.

```
For each cell in columns("c:c")
If cell.value = "TRUE" Then
'vba is required for  selecting corresponding cells in columns A and B 
Next cell
Else:
exit sub
End if
end sub
```

please make suitable corrections

Comment: what ahve you tried so far?

Comment: hi simico, please look atabove edited code. just i wrote roughly bcoz i dont to know much about coding.

Comment: you wnat to select only first row where in column C is FASLE, or all rows where in column C is false?

Comment: i want to select all the rows which contain false

Comment: what columns in thouse rows should be selected?

Comment: cells of column A and B should be selected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    'change Sheet1 to suit
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each c In .Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
            If UCase(c.Text) = "FALSE" Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = .Range("A" & c.Row).Resize(, 2)
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, .Range("A" & c.Row).Resize(, 2))
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    End With

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: YES its perfect hit. Thats what I needed.  thanks simico. If you dont mind can i have your email ID or where can i take your help directly other than this website?